# randomize image without reloading page php

Tags: php, image, random

I am looking forward to build a page that displays a single image
what i want to achieve is that, on clicking a 'next' button, the image should be changed but the page shouldn't be reloaded.

I am gonna be storing the images in a folder and the names would be random.
I have worked with php and a bit of javascript so i have the basic knowledge.

I googled the issue, some say use Ajax, some say use jquery. I am just unable to figure out what approach should i take.

Any help would really be appreciated

Comment: you can do this by ajax+jquery(javascript) .. its not possible with only php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JavaScript, just change the image's source.

```
document.getElementById('image-id').src = 'new-image.png';
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but i would like to know that whether in the part .src= 'new-image.png' can i use .src= '<?php $variable ?>'; where $variable contains the filename of my image?

Comment: @user1216752 no you can not use since php   execute at server side .. to change by php you have no choice than ajax or websocket

Comment: @user1216752 If you want to show image fetch from server side use ajax

Comment: Is there any link or tutorial which you could provide me to deal with it? I barely have any knowedge of Ajax

Comment: @user1216752 I don't think you need to use ajax; you can just preload all of the image names on the page

Comment: @ExplosionPills can you please give me a very small example of how that can be done or any link from which i can get the knowledge?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Javascript to display any image

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

       function changeImage() {
           document.getElementById("iRock").src = "iRock_Happy.png";
       }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
       <img src="iRock.png" id= "iRock" onclick="changeImage()">
 </body>
```

Comment: so if i am getting this correct , what this script would do is on default (i mean when the page is just opened) it would display image 'iRock.png' and once clicked on the image itself , it would dislpay image 'iRock_happy.png' ?

Comment: is there anyway you could suggest that instead of 'iRock_happy.png' i could put up a variable that always has a random image name so that whenever the image is clicked a random image is displayed ?